# View agent 000 in Wazuh dashboard views

Tags: wazuh

When I run "/var/ossec/bin/agent_control -l" I see an agent with id 000.

```
 ID: 000, Name: org1 (server), IP: 127.0.0.1, Active/Local
```

However, this agent is not available in the wazuh dashboard.

If I go to the "events" view, I can see the alerts from the machine associated with 000, but these don't show up in other layouts. For example, the Security Configuration Assessment Inventory view is unavailable, even though I can search through the events manually and find SCA alerts for it.

[image]

What configuration is needed to use the 000 agent across the dashboard? Or where can I find log information about it not connecting?

Answer (score 0):

The agent with ID **000** corresponds to an **embedded Wazuh manager agent**, it is not an external agent, the visibility of this agent is filtered due to its nature and certain views are by default, such as the **Security configuration assessment** view, where in the **Events** section it is shown by default with pre-defined filters of this agent, this embedded agent is clarified as both **manager.name** and **agent.name** (same value)

[image]

This behavior is a defined behavior and doing some research I found this issue that may be related: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/issues/489

I would recommend that you create an issue with the behavior you expect in the https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/issues repository so that the team can work on adding this functionality after evaluating it.

About this specific question:

> Or where can I find log information about it not connecting?

As I have said, agent 000 is an embedded agent, it does not connect or disconnect, and its behavior is associated with the operation of the Wazuh manager itself, the logs can be found in **/var/ossec/logs/ossec.log**

Comment: Good find on the pull request, but I think they've refactored the app since then. I'd rever their change locally if I could find it, since it looks like it is only a view filter.

Comment: Yes, that is why I recommend opening an issue directly in the repository so that it can be incorporated into the roadmap. When I answered you, I notified the team about this and yes, it's old and there have been multiple code refactorings where this configuration has been kept

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested in how to show agent 000 in the list of agents.
You can use the search query:

```
status~e ) or id>-1 and ( status~e
```

This will show agent 000 in the list of agents, but you cannot do anything more, the agent has no group, and you cannot attach it to any group directly.

Groups are preserved in the global SQLite database.